# Android Studio Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader, android-viewmodel

I am new in Android, I have finished some Android app development courses and now I am trying to apply what I learned. I've chosen a news app for it. It will extract news' from 5-10 source and display them in recyclerview.

I recognized that the course materials I used is outdated. I've used AsynctaskLoader to handle internet connection issues but now in official Android documentation it says *"Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and LiveData."*

My question is should I convert my code to comply with ViewModels and LiveData or would Asynctask handle my task (or any other suggestion)? As I mentioned I only want to extract news data from a couple of source and display them in the app. It seems I don't need data storage feature. But, for now I have added two news source and the app seems to load news data a little bit late. Does this latency has something to do with using loaders? Would using viewmodels speed up news loading task (especially when there are lots of news source)?

Comment: Note that only the framework Loaders have been deprecated, the Support Library version of Loaders is not deprecated.

Comment: @ianhanniballake well the doc in the source code from the support library explicitly says "deprecated" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WqhpZbZUSDlQNb1SZNVmfPbIW7Y31QZy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Raykud - that's because you're supposed to use [LoaderManager.getInstance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html#getInstance(T)) as per the [actual source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity.java#620), not that Support library Loaders are deprecated.

Comment: @ianhanniballake so its not documented. I belive it should be properly documented with the annotation 'see' or with a reference to use the new methods like the native fragments which refer to use the support ones.

Comment: @Raykud - as per the source code, there's definitely a link to the new class, so this looks like a display issue with the documentation on developer.android.com - it looks like it does show correctly on the [androidx FragmentActivity documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#getSupportLoaderManager())

Comment: @ianhanniballake androidX documentation does differs from the normal one? as I'm seeing the link you provided is from androidX

Comment: @Raykud - as per the [AndroidX page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/), all of the Support Library has been fully replaced with their AndroidX equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loaders are good because of its ability to handle life cycle, but it is not as efficient as LiveData and ViewModel. If you care about performance, speed and being latest, use Android Architecture Components (LiveData, ViewModel), also, you don't have to stick to the old system of doing things, you can write a simple AsyncTask and wrap it with ViewModel and LiveData. It works like a magic and better than Loaders. For information on how to wrap AsyncTask in LiveData and ViewModel, visit https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lifecycle-aware-data-loading-with-android-architecture-components-f95484159de4

Comment: For my app I think I don't need database feature, I am just fetching data from internet and display it. But as i understand from the new android architecture, it is a bit aimed for using databases etc... (I looked at the MVVM model)  Actually I am confused because of this, since I don't need database feature.

Comment: Please note that if you really want to use database with Android Architecture Components, you would use ViewModel and LiveData with ROOM. Room is another part of Android Architecture Components that deals with database, you can totally forget Contents Provider if you use Room.

Comment: Please note, AAC is not designed for database only, it is designed for running background tasks e.g Networking, Database etc,

Answer (score 6):

If you've already written it with Loaders there's no reason to rush to change it.  Deprecated doesn't mean gone.  And no, Loaders don't add significant performance penalty-  any perf issues would be elsewhere in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and LiveData. ViewModels survive configuration changes like Loaders but with less boilerplate. LiveData provides a lifecycle-aware way of loading data that you can reuse in multiple ViewModels. You can also combine LiveData using MediatorLiveData , and any observable queries, such as those from a Room database, can be used to observe changes to the data. ViewModels and LiveData are also available in situations where you do not have access to the LoaderManager, such as in a Service. Using the two in tandem provides an easy way to access the data your app needs without having to deal with the UI lifecycle.